# Symfony 2 and Database structure with yml

Tags: symfony, doctrine, yaml

I am getting familiar to Symfony-2 after having good experience with Symfony 1.4.

I was searching for a good tutorial of creating the database from a yml file (or several files), and could not find any.

Is it possible to define relations between tables and constrains in the yml file? The only documentation I found talks about metadata in the Entity file.

Answer (score 4):

Be aware: some kind of constraints will not work properly: e.g. `fixed` in a column of type string is not translated as `CHAR` if you use MySQL PDO, but as `VARCHAR`. Also i found some undocumented constraints for YALM:

**Unique index**

```
MyCompany\MyApp\MyClass:
  type: entity
  table: myclass
  uniqueConstraints:
    UNIQ_NAME:
    columns: [column1, column2]
```

**General index**:

```
MyCompany\MyApp\MyClass:
  type: entity
  table: myclass
  indexes:
    IDX_NAME:
    columns: [column1, column2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [Doctrine manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/association-mapping.html)... You can switch between *PHP Annotations*, *XML* and *YAML* for every example.